# FAQPage with groups of questions

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

How do you structure the JSON-LD for a `FAQPage` where you have groups of questions on a page?

Example:

> **Questions about Billing**
> Question 1
> Answer
> Question 2
> Answer
>
> **Questions about Shipping**
> Question 1
> Answer 1

```
{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"FAQPage"
,"name":"Frequently asked questions"
,"mainEntity":[
    {"@type":"Question","name":"How do i see my previous bills?","acceptedAnswer":{"@type":"Answer","text":"Click the link that says 'Previous bills'."}}
    ,{"@type":"Question","name":"How do a pay my bill?","acceptedAnswer":{"@type":"Answer","text":"Call 1-800-pay-bill"}}
    ,{"@type":"Question","name":"How do i update my profile?","acceptedAnswer":{"@type":"Answer","text":"Click the link that says 'Edit profile'."}}
]}
```

Comment: Why would you want to use structured data on the FAQ page?  If you are searching for some structured data to use, you probably don't know what you are doing and you are looking for structured data for the wrong reasons.

Comment: Well you got me there, i wouldn't be asking a question if i knew what i was doing.

Comment: There is a QAPage structured data that you can add a question and answer to. there's also a new FAQPage structured type that i assume you can add many questions to. our page has groups of FAQ topics but don't know how to add them as groups. are you saying the FAQPage type shouldn't be used?

Comment: If you know that somebody is going to use it and you want to make your data available for that purpose then go ahead and use structured data.    If you are asking "which structured data should I use", it means you don't know who would be using it.  At best you are making your site more machine readable and somebody will stumble upon that.  You are probably just wasting your time.  At worst, you are making your content easy to steal.  Lots of people seem to be implementing structured data assuming that Google uses all of it, but Google only uses a few types for rich snippets.

Comment: Did you try something? If yes, please [edit] your question to include a JSON-LD example showing what you’ve got / what you’ve tried.

Comment: I have added some sample json. You can see that its just question, question, question. i want to somehow denote groups of questions like "Billing questions" or "Profile questions", if possible. Maybe i use multiple FAQPage types?

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer to this. It's correct the way i have it only it should be using ListItem in the mainEntity instead of an array. no need to add the topic of each set of questions.